# Cell Fracture Hallow Shards

Tags: add-on

I was trying to make a rock-like texture for my mesh by using cell fracture, but every time I used the feature - the shards appeared hallow. Is there a procedure I missed; or is there something I need to do with this outer covering that normally appears after I apply the cell fracture?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Well, when I applied location, rotation, and scale - cell fracture worked perfectly. It was hard to find the answer via google lol.
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

For those wondering how the OP had applied location, rotation and scale, the below may help.

For applying location, rotation and scale or a combination of these three:

- Make sure you are in object mode and not edit mode.
- select the object you want to apply rotation, location and scale to.
- press Ctrl + A. A menu will appear. There you can choose what you want to apply. You can apply any one or all three too.

Note: Another thing which can cause problems sometimes with addons is improper normals.

To make normals consistent:

- Select the object and go into edit mode
- press A to select everything
- press Ctrl + N to make normals consistent

Comment: Can you add these to the original answer as a more general how to? Thanks.

Comment: ...who is @Marain ?

Comment: Someone had asked how to apply location rotation scale. I think it was this Marain person seems like the comment is no longer there for some reason

Comment: @iKlsR I don't think I can as I never wrote the original answer. Seems like the OP answered his/her own question.